# How to Create an multiple image rollover effect like facebook album

Tags: javascript, css

When i hover on facebook album ,multiple images will change ,by using the rollover effect i can change only one image, how to change the multiple images when mouse over on one image,>?

Comment: Can we see some of your code? Or at least an example. Thanks

Comment: This describes a feature of Facebook that I've never noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either javascript or CSS - the two are essentially exclusively mutual in relation to rollovers and both have positive and negative issues (if a browser has no scripting the user won't be able to see the javascript rollover, if the browser is IE, it may have limited support for CSS rollovers).

[See here for CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)
[And here for Javascript](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/tutorials/javascript-rollovers/).

But I'd advice against attempting to exactly emulate any particular website. Particularly a complicated one such as Facebook where much of the code is obfuscated.

Comment: You'd almost certainly want to use JavaScript for this. IE7+ support CSS hovers; while IE6 doesn't, most people dont support IE6 anymore because nobody uses it.